# Hibernate Search: Is it possible to get multiple fields in same hit while doing search using hibernate search?

Tags: search, hibernate-search

Let's say we have indexed table A with fields x, y and z. When I make a search for any keyword/phrase (let's say cow), I want to get a single hit that shows 'Cow' has occurrence in field 'x' (if any), field  'y' (if any) and field 'z'(if any) for same id.
Please let me know if the question is still vague. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by "hit" ? Are you asking for database query ?

Comment: Hibenate Search takes care of database query underneath. 'Hit' in my context means a 'match' a particular column and row

Comment: Also, I figured out the solution. I was able to extract the 'Explanation' element of the hit that tells me all the columns where the 'match' for a search phrase/keyword occurs for an unique row.

Comment: queryBuilder.keyword().onFields("x", "y","z").matching("cow")